# Connes-Chern pairing, compatibility with periodicity operator in the odd case

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, cyclic-homology

Let $A$ be an algebra (say unital). For an odd (say $2n-1$) cyclic cocycle $\varphi$ and a class in $K_1(A)$ represented by invertible $u$ we define 
$$\langle [\varphi],[u] \rangle:=\frac{2^{-(2n+1)}}{(n-\frac12)(n-\frac32) \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac32 \cdot  \frac12}\varphi(u^{-1}-1,u-1,...,u^{-1}-1,u-1).$$
Let $S$ be a periodicity operator in cyclic cohomology: $S: HC^n(A) \to HC^{n+2}(A)$. It is defined as the composition of two connecting homomorphisms in two long exact sequence: it can be also defined directly at the level of cocycles as $S=-b(1+2\lambda+3\lambda^2+...+(n+2)\lambda^{n+1})b'$ where $\lambda$ is the cyclic operator, $b$ is a boundary in Hochschild (or cyclic) cohomology and $b'$ is $b$ without the last term.

> How to prove that $\langle [\varphi],[u] \rangle=\langle S[\varphi],[u] \rangle$?

It is left as an exercise in Connes book or in the IHES paper: it is also left as an exercise in Khalkhali ,,Basic Noncommutative Geometry'' book. In this book the even case is treated using the formula above for the $S$ operator. Connes works with the rather different formula for operator $S$ using the closed graded trace $\hat{\varphi}$ defined on the universal differential graded algebra (on $\Omega^n(A)$ precisely) by the formula
$$\widehat{\varphi}(a_0da_1...da_n)=\varphi(a_0,...,a_n).$$

I haven't found any place in the literature where it is carefully verified.

Comment: You cannot use Khalkhali's book as a reference, it contains a lot of handwaving arguments and mistakes. I suggest you stick with Connes.

Comment: I suggest you check that the cyclic homology-cyclic cohomology pairing is compatible with the respective periodicity operators. Then check that the Chern character from K-theory to cyclic homology is compatible with the periodicity operator.

Comment: @YYY However in Khalkhali's book the even case is treated and the proof works fine (using the formula $S=-b(1+2\lambda+...+(n+2)\lambda^{n+1})b'$. However Connes works with another definition, of $S$ using differentials (and also treats the even case). Therefore I'm not sure which formula would be more useful in order to deal with the odd case.

Comment: @vap Indeed, however I don't see why the proof for cyclic homology would be easier (it is rather the same computional problem).